# How can I replace a regex substring match in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, substring

```
var str   = 'asd-0.testing';
var regex = /asd-(\d)\.\w+/;

str.replace(regex, 1);
```

That replaces the entire string `str` with `1`. I want it to replace the matched substring instead of the whole string. Is this possible in Javascript?

Comment: FYI, all of the solutions are pretty complex. You just want to replace the match, right? Easy way to do it, without modifying your regex at all, is like this: ```str.replace(regex, "$`1$'")``` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

Answer (score 162):

```
var str   = 'asd-0.testing';
var regex = /(asd-)\d(\.\w+)/;
str = str.replace(regex, "$11$2");
console.log(str);
```

Or if you're sure there won't be any other digits in the string:

```
var str   = 'asd-0.testing';
var regex = /\d/;
str = str.replace(regex, "1");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: or using function: 
'asd-0.testing'.replace(/(asd-)\d(\.\w+)/, function(mystring, arg1, arg2){return arg1 + 'mynumber' + arg2})

Comment: is there any answer where you DONT know the structure of the regex? here you are basically creating a new regex with two matches

Comment: It is good to know that you need braces () around the part you want as $1, $2 etc.

Answer (score 62):

using `str.replace(regex, $1);`:

```
var str   = 'asd-0.testing';
var regex = /(asd-)\d(\.\w+)/;

if (str.match(regex)) {
    str = str.replace(regex, "$1" + "1" + "$2");
}
```

Edit: adaptation regarding the comment

Comment: I want to replace the substring with '1' not the entire string with the substring

Answer (score 31):

I would get the part before and after what you want to replace and put them either side.

Like:

```
var str   = 'asd-0.testing';
var regex = /(asd-)\d(\.\w+)/;

var matches = str.match(regex);

var result = matches[1] + "1" + matches[2];

// With ES6:
var result = `${matches[1]}1${matches[2]}`;
```

Comment: +1 I personally like having the collection of matches to frack with.

Comment: I agree, having the matched set available is more readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

I think the simplest way to achieve your goal is this:

```
var str   = 'asd-0.testing';
var regex = /(asd-)(\d)(\.\w+)/;
var anyNumber = 1;
var res = str.replace(regex, `$1${anyNumber}$3`);
```

Answer (score 3):

A **One-Liner** based on @Greg7000's answer  which uses a replacer method:

```
'asd-0.testing'
  .replace(
    /(asd-)\d(\.\w+)/,
    (match: string, p1: string, p2: string) => { 
      return `${p1}1${p2}`; 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like the liberty provided by the [replacer technique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_the_replacement) (Search for '**Specifying a function as the replacement**' section). This is also simplier to debug in details.

```
function replacer(match, p1, p2, offset, string) {
    console.log('match = ' + match);
    console.log('p1 = ' + p1);
    console.log('p2 = ' + p2);
    console.log('offset = ' + offset);
    console.log('string = ' + string);
    custom_op = p1 + 1 + p2;

    return custom_op;
}

var str = 'asd-0.testing';
var regex = /(asd-)\d(\.\w+)/;

matches = str.match(regex)

res = str.replace(regex, replacer);
console.log(res);

// ----OUTPUT----
// match = asd-0.testing
// p1 = asd-
// p2 = .testing
// offset = 0
// string = asd-0.testing
// asd-1.testing
```

**NOTE**: To ease the identification of regex groups, consider using https://regex101.com/