# Javascript regex match number after string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string

```
/results?radius=4000&newFilter=true
```

and I need to replace `radius=4000` with `radius=n` where n is a variable.

How can I use `String.replace()` method with regex to match that part?

Comment: It would be better to create an object literal of your params, then simply replace the value and redirect with new params.

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I replace a regex substring match in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598042/how-can-i-replace-a-regex-substring-match-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `/radius=\d+/` to match "radius=" followed by any number of digits. With this we can use the `replace()` method to replace it with the desired value:

```js
var str = "/results?radius=4000&newFilter=true";
var replacement = 123;

var newStr = str.replace(/radius=\d+/, "radius=" + replacement);

console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: Both `match` parameter in anonymous function, as well as that anonymous function itself are unnecessary. Why not just `str.replace(/radius=\d+/, "radius=" + replacement)`? Also, `newStr` has missing semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all parameters you can try this :

```js
function getParams(uri) {

 var params = {},
        tokens,
        re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;
        
    while (tokens = re.exec(uri)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])] = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
    }
    return params;
}

var str='/results?radius=4000&newFilter=true';

str = str.substring(str.indexOf("?"));
params = getParams(str);

console.log(params);
console.log('radius => ', params['radius']);
```

This answer is from this post: [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters#1099670)

Answer (score 1):

It should be as easy as

```
var str='/results?radius=4000&newFilter=true';
var n = 1234;

str = str.replace(/(radius=)(\d+)/, "$1" + n);
```

Comment: Why to use capturing groups and backreference if it could be avoided? Especially second capturing group seem unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "/results?radius=4000&newFilter=true"; 
// or window.location.href for current url
var captured = /radius=([^&]+)/.exec(url)[1]; // your 4000
var newValue = 5000;
url = url.replace(captured, newValue);
```

by this way you can use it to get all your requested parameters too
and it is not decimal binded

Comment: `window.location.search.substr(1)` would be better imho as a comment.

Comment: @TimVermaelen possible, has to been benchmarked what is faster

Comment: I don't think it's faster really, just more expressive on the part you want to match.
If the '?' is not an issue, the `substr(1)` can be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

### ES6 with regex using positive lookbehind

```js
const string       = '/results?radius=4000&newFilter=true',
      n            = '1234',
      changeRadius = (radius) => string.replace(/(?<=radius=)\d+/, n);

console.log(changeRadius(n));
```

```css
/* Output console formatting */
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; }
```

- `changeRadius` is function that takes one parameter (`radius`) and performs replacement.
- About the regex: `\d+` gets as many digits as possible, `(?<=STRING)` is a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

#### Other regex

Body of `changeRadius()` function can be replaced with `string.replace(/radius=\d+/, 'radius=' + n)`. It probably has better performance, but original regex is more direct translation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturing without remembering the match to capture only the numerical value after 'radius='.

```
var url = "/results?radius=4000&newFilter=true";

var radius = 123;

var newUrl = url.replace(/(?:radius=){1}(\d+)/, radius);

console.log(newUrl); // logs '/results?radius=4000&newFilter=true'0
```

'

Comment: First thing, `str` and `replacement` are undefined. Change `url` to `str` and `radius` to `replacement`.
Second thing, you miss `=` after `radius`.
Third thing, you forgot `'radius=' + ` before `replacement` at position of the second parameter of `replace()` function.
Forth thing, why the needless `{1}` and capturing group around `\d+`?
And the last thing, I don't know if you would agree, but to me positive lookbehind seem to be better fit rather than non-capturing group.

Comment: Thanks i fixes the str and replacement, i actually was tinkering in my editor and pasted the wrong script.

Comment: This still gives `"/results?123&newFilter=true"` instead of `/results?radius=123&newFilter=true`. Once again, you forgot `'radius=' +` before `radius` at position of the second parameter of `replace()` function.