# Add variable into string

Tags: javascript, regex

All I need to do here is to add a variable before each specific string.

Example:

```
var exampleString = "blabla:test abcde 123test:123";
var formattedString = "el.blabla:test abcde el.123test:123";
```

As you can see, when I have something like "XXX:XXX", I need to add a variable before it.

I have the Regex to find "XXX:"

```
var regex = new RegExp(/\w+([aA-zZ]:)/g)
```

But when I try to replace it, it replaces all instead of adding the variable "el."

```
var exampleString = "blabla:test abcde 123test:123";
var formattedString = exampleString.replace(new RegExp(/\w+([aA-zZ]:)/g), 'el.');
// formattedString is now "el.test abcde el.123"
// Instead of "el.blabla:test abcde el.123test:123"
```

Could anyone makes this work ? Thanks :)

Source: [Javascript Regex: How to put a variable inside a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029109/javascript-regex-how-to-put-a-variable-inside-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598042/how-can-i-replace-a-regex-substring-match-in-javascript) may help you. Actually the logic is that you can use `()` to group thee desired substring. And the in replace string you can use "$1" to use the first matched group

Comment: Thank you, it's a useful thread too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var exampleString = "blabla:test abcde 123test:123";
var formattedString = exampleString.replace(/\w*:\w*/gi, 'el.$&');
console.log(formattedString);
```

Regex use and Explanation Here https://regex101.com/r/U2KeXi/3

Sample Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/a8wyLb0g/2/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your working example and your help, I understand it well with the Regex explanation :)

Comment: No need using capturing groups when you need to refer to the whole match value, use `.replace(/\w+:\w+/gi, 'el.$&')`. If you use [`\w*:\w*`](https://regex101.com/r/U2KeXi/2), you will add `el.` before any `:`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks , i have updated the answer and the links.

Comment: I checked it as the best answer because It matches the correct string without changing it, and it's also working with alphanumeric characters :)

Comment: @NicolasLeucci We always have room for improvement, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `^` to match only at the beginning. And remove the `g` modifier, since you only want to replace once, not every time.

There's also no reason to use `new RegExp()`, just use a `RegExp` literal.

In the replacement string, you need to use `$&` to copy the original string into the replacement.

```js
var exampleString = "blabla:test abcde 123test:123";
var formattedString = exampleString.replace(/^\w+[a-z]:/i, 'el.$&');
console.log(formattedString);
```

Also, the proper way to match all letters in either case is with `[A-Za-z]`, not `[aA-zZ]`, or use the `i` modifier to make the regexp case-insensitive. Your regexp matches all characters in the range `A-z`, which includes lots of punctuation characters that are between the uppercase letters and lowercase letters in the ASCII code.

Comment: Thank you ! I actually need to append all iteration in my string

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
exampleString.replace(/(\w*):(\w*)/gi, 'el.$1:$2');
```

REGEXP explanation :

capturing group (\w*) is for capturing any alphabets in any number of occurance,
$1 and $2 specifies the first and second capturing group.

Comment: Explain what does it mean `$1` and `$2`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function like `insertAt` instead `replace`, see following example:

```js
String.prototype.insertAt=function(index, string) { 
  return this.substr(0, index) + string + this.substr(index);
}

var exampleString = "blabla:test abcde 123test:123";
var regex = new RegExp(/\w+([aA-zZ]:)/g)
var formattedString = exampleString;

while ( (result = regex.exec(exampleString)) ) {
    formattedString = formattedString.insertAt(result.index, "el.");
}

console.log(formattedString);
```

I hope it helps you, bye.