# Replacing colons between spaces in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using Javascript to manipulate items in ZOTERO.

I have multiple items whose title contains `" : "` (a colon between spaces).

I want to replace this with `", "` (a comma and a space).

For example:

```
This is : an example
```

should be

```
This is, an example
```

Can anyone tell me if the `.replace` statement in my code is correct?

```
var fieldName = "title";
 
var fieldID = Zotero.ItemFields.getID(fieldName);
var s = new Zotero.Search();
s.libraryID = ZoteroPane.getSelectedLibraryID();
s.addCondition(fieldName, 'contains', '  ');
var ids = await s.search();
if (!ids.length) {
    return "No items found";
}
await Zotero.DB.executeTransaction(async function () {
    for (let id of ids) {
        let item = await Zotero.Items.getAsync(id);
        let mappedFieldID = Zotero.ItemFields.getFieldIDFromTypeAndBase(item.itemTypeID, fieldName);
        let fieldID = mappedFieldID || fieldID;
        item.setField(fieldID, item.getField(fieldID).replace(/[\s:\s]/g, ', '));
        await item.save({
            skipDateModifiedUpdate: true
        });
    }
});
return ids.length + " item(s) updated";
```

Comment: `[\s:\s]` is whitespace or `:`. You'd want `\s[:]\s` or probably more likely space:space (SO won't format spaces in code blocks correctly). `\s` is any white space, not just a space.

Comment: Looks fine at first glance; did you test this? Are you encountering errors? Unexpected results? Please clarify the issue you have.

Comment: https://regexper.com/#%2F%5B%5Cs%3A%5Cs%5D%2Fg

Comment: No, I did not test my script yet because I will be changing hundreds of items and would like to avoid setting the whole DB back to the latest backup. If I understood @user3783243 correctly, [\s:\s] would replace any colon with a comma, not just colons between spaces?

Comment: Correct, any colon or space. https://regex101.com/r/mjVNIM/1/

Answer (score 5):

[`String.prototype.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) should work just fine in this case

```js
const test = 'This is : an example'
console.log(test.replaceAll(' : ', ', '));
```

> **Note** *IE* does not support this JavaScript built-in: [Can I use...](https://caniuse.com/?search=replaceall)
>
> As an alternative, you can use a global `//g` [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598042/how-can-i-replace-a-regex-substring-match-in-javascript):
>
> ```js
> const test = 'This is : an example'
> console.log(test.replace(/\ :\ /g, ', '));
> ```

Comment: Good answer: no regex needed!

Comment: You can also use `String.split(' : ')` and `Array.join(', ')`. Not the best way to solve this problem, but its still a useful tool in some other situations if you don't know about it!

Comment: This looks straightforward, but not sure this is supported in ZOTERO. I am using the in-built "Run JavaScript" console: https://www.zotero.org/support/dev/client_coding/javascript_api

Comment: There is no need to escape the spaces in the regex, `/ : /g` works fine. Escaping spaces is only needed when "[free-spacing](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#freespacing)" mode (`x` flag) is active (not supported in JavaScript).

Comment: `.replaceAll` produced an error, so I will try regex again: `TypeError: item.getField(...).replaceAll is not a function`